# How can I convert mixed datetime formats into one?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am facing a little problem with time data in a dataframe. I am trying to convert mixed formats with single digits and slashes (2/19/22) as well as double digits with hyphen (2020-02-19) to zero padded data with point (19.02.2022).

Data:

```
d = {'Date':['24.06.2022','2022-01-23', '7/2/22',  '9/23/18', '23.05.2022'], 
      'Flight': ['Rome', 'Zurich', 'Dallas', 'Madrid', 'Stockholm']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

My code:

```
def autoconvert_datetime(value):
    formats = ['%-m/%-d/%y', '%Y-%m-%d']  
    result_format = '%d.%m.%Y' 
    for dt_format in formats:
        try:
            dt_obj = datetime.strptime(value, dt_format)
            return dt_obj.strftime(result_format)
        except Exception as e:  # throws exception when format doesn't match
            pass
    return value  

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(autoconvert_datetime)
```

For other datetime formats it worked without any problem.

Comment: If you can't say for sure if day or month comes first, you have a problem. If you mix in 2-digit years, the fun gets even bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and let Pandas infers the format:

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df)

# Output
         Date     Flight      Date2
0  24.06.2022       Rome 2022-06-24
1  2022-01-23     Zurich 2022-01-23
2      7/2/22     Dallas 2022-07-02
3     9/23/18     Madrid 2018-09-23
4  23.05.2022  Stockholm 2022-05-23
```

If you want more control, you can directly use [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) used by Pandas.

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually forgot about `pd.to_datetime`. All good now!

Comment: What if `7/2/22` means Feb 7th? Letting pandas / dateutil's parser *guess* won't solve the actual problem I think.

Comment: @FObersteiner. You can use `dayfirst` parameter but I'm agree it's not so simple.

Comment: @FObersteiner That's true. In this case I know it since the original data is messy, but in correct order. Is there another solution?